# Implementation for Rails model that might not need a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, types, model

I'm trying to construct a system in Rails where I've got a Project model with a "type" column, and I'm not sure whether if I should explicitly store the type as a string in the projects table, or if I should store a type_id instead.  The thing is, I feel like it would be stupid to create a type model; Types cannot be created or destroyed, there are simply a fixed number of them.  But if I don't create a model, the only other way I can think to do it would be to create a Type class in /lib which has a get_name(type_id) method, and this seems like total overkill.

If I decided to just store the string, I'd be using unnecessary space, and filtering by type would be weird.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Careful! the column name `type` will trigger the single table inheritance mechanism (maybe that's what you're going for?)

Comment: Good eye, you're right, that will cause a problem.  I can just switch it to a more specific name though.  Either way, my question still stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure the types are a fixed set you can define some numeric constant in the `Project` model and just store these number in a column of your `projects` table.

Here an example (not tested of course) where I call the column `category_id` to avoid to use the `type` name that would cause problems [as rjz said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729261/implementation-for-rails-model-that-might-not-need-a-database#comment13937377_10729261):

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Project categories are constants
  CHEAP_PROJECT = 1
  SOUND_PROJECT = 2
  GRAPHIC_PROJECT = 3
  SECRET_PROJECT = 4

  # Force project_category_id to be a valid category identifier
  validates :category_id, :inclusion => {:in => 1..4}

  # At this point you can use the constants
  # Here an example of a scope to get the secret projects
  scope :secret_projects, where(:category_id => SECRET_PROJECT)
end
```

Be sure to validate the `category_id` values to be one of which you defined.
Once you have these constans you can even use from other places using something like `Project::SOUND_PROJECT`.

I think is a solution pretty clear, but if your requirements change (they *always* change...) you have to create a model and insert these project categories maintaining these identifiers.